# How to call a method with arguments in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I am new to the programming language Smalltalk and I can't seem to figure out how to call a method with arguments. I've been playing around with some code and created some methods, like for example (in GNU Smalltalk):

```
bin: n num: k [
      | i |
      i := 1.
      1 to:k do:[:j|
          i := i * 2.
      ].
      ^i
  ]
```

I would now like to call this function and actually get an answer, like for example: bin: 4 num: 2 (don't know how to do this). How can I do that? Is it even right to write 'bin: n num: k' when creating a method like I have done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: GNU Smalltalk has a tutorial: https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual/html_node/Tutorial.html In the chapter "Creating Classes" it describes how to define classes, add methods to them, and call those methods. As an example, it lets you define a class for bank accounts.

Comment: Can you create a function without a class that takes parameters?

Answer (score 4):

First, you need a receiver object, on which you want to invoke that method. You did not indicate in which class you have created your method, so I will just assume that you called it `MyClass`.

```
| myObject |
myObject := MyClass new.
```

Then you can send that message to (invoke that method on) myObject like this:

```
myObject bin: 4 num: 2
```

So you just write the message send (which will invoke the method) after the receiver.